# How can I take dampening into account in mass-spring-damper simulation in Simulink?

Tags: matlab, simulation, simulink

I have been given the following assignment:

We have a spring-mass-dampening system that has only one degree of freedom. Basically hanging down.
The mass of the object is 10 kg. It is attached to a spring that has the spring constant of 21 000 N.

The system is being disturbed with a sine wave force, which pushes the mass to the direction of its movement (basically down). The angular frequency of the force is 45.8 radians per second and the amplitude is 500 Newtons.

Now, the dampening force of the system is the following:

[Dampening force](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIs9n.png)

I couldn't make a formula here so I used an image.

I am supposed to simulate the system in Simulink and find out the amplitude of the vibration the system will settle to permanently during 10 seconds.

The issue is, my simulation meets a singularity.

Here is my attempt:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DPXR.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmMDw.png)

The error is here:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdIbD.png)

I am really at loss. What am I doing wrong? Why isn't the simulation working? Should I add the dampening differently?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You simulate the following system (`x` position, `xt` velocity, `xtt` acceleration) :

`xtt = 1/m( u - k*x - c*(xt)^2)`

When `xt > 0` then there is an opossite force slowing the system (damping force). When `xt < 0` then there is a force in the same direction,( because `1(xt)^2` ) thus the bigger the speed in the negative direction, the bigger the "damping force" in the negative direction, and the system is **unstable**. Thus x goes to inf and you cannot intergrate.

To fix it, you have to model the damping force correctly. It is always in the opposite direction of the velocity.

Hint 1:

> So you have to simulate  `xtt = 1/m( u - k*x - sign(xt)*c*(xt)^2)`

Hint 2:

> You have to use the [sign block](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/sign.html), and [matrix multiply](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/product.html).

> [image]

Comment: Thank you very much! My teacher didn't mention anything about the sign module. You have saved my course grade :D Thank you again!

Comment: It's nothing. I would like to tell you this: 1. As the error was after some time (0.1 secs) then the code compiles, and **probably** it has to do with infinities/instabilities or even wrong logic. 2. As it happens after some time, you can see the scope until that moment. That is how i found out that the system is unstable. 
Also, If you want accept the answer to close the question.

Answer (score -1):

In a traditional mass-spring damper system, the x_dot term is not squared. Your damping force would become F_damp = C * x_dot.